# ng route not working directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

Can I do ng-view in angular directives. I tried but this error showing.

**Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.13/$injector/unpr?p0=%24templateRequestProvider%20%3C-%20%24templateRequest%20%3C-%20%24route%20%3C-%20ngViewDirective**

my code :

index.html

```
<body ng-app="Learning">
    <div  ng-controller="learning">
        <div ng-switch-when="1" >
            <div introduction-page></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

app.js

```
var Learn = angular.module("Learning",['ngRoute']);

Learn.directive("introductionPage", function() {
    return {
        restrict:'EA',
        transclude:false,   
        templateUrl:'views/intro.html',
        replace:true,
        controller: introController
    }

    function introController($scope,$http,$location) {
        $scope.onClick = function() {
            $location.path('course');
        }
    }   
});

Learn.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/course', {
            templateUrl : 'views/course-ch1.html',
            controller  : 'courseController'
        })

        .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
});

function courseController($scope) {
    alert("in course");
}
```

intro.html

```
<div style="width:100%;height:662px">

    INTRODUCTION........

    <div ng-view></div>
    <input type="button" style="width:100px;height:40px;" label="enter" ng-click="onClick()">

</div>
```

Is it possible to do this way?

Thanks

Comment: You should use ngView in index.html rather than intro.html

Comment: is it possible to use ng-view in intro.html? can i do here . Is it right way?

Comment: I don't think to use like that...

Answer (score 1):

You can have ng-view in directive but with the help of transclude : true,property:-

Like

```
<div introduction-page>
    <ng-view></ng-view>
</div>
```

As shown in example here :- http://plnkr.co/edit/0813dA?p=preview

Comment: The OP is asking if he can use ngView in intro.html than index.html, do you recommend to use?

Comment: I was just explaining he can put it into directive by transclude but definately "NO" for intro.htm.